# Receiving an XML post and parsing

Tags: c#, validation, xml

I need to receive an XML post then process all the data, and do whatever I need to do with the data. I could be receiving anywhere from 60 to 100 values. I know what all the elements are going to be, and all except one is mandatory. For billing, it could either be credit card info or checking info, so I need to check the first child's name to see what the billing type is.

Here is a cut-down example:

```xml
<XmlData>
    <FirstName>FirstName</FirstName>
    <LastName>LastName</LastName>
    <Address>666 S st.</Address>
    <Email>email@email.com</Email>
    <City>Beverly Hills</City>
    <Zip>90210</Zip>
    <PhoneNumber>5555555555</PhoneNumber>
    <!-- 14more nodes -->
    <Billing> 
        <CCType>Visa</CCType>
        <CCNumber>55554443332221</CCNumber>
        <! -- 8 More Nodes for billing -->
    </Billing>
</XmlData>
```

Now, here is how I am handling processing the data. In my `Page_Load`, I am first calling a method that will verify the XML is well formatted and not null(not posting this code). Next, I call a method that will read all the data and assign it private fields using LINQ to XML.

```cs
private string firstName = string.Empty;
private string lastName = string.Empty;
private string address = string.Empty;
private string email= string.Empty;
private string city= string.Empty;
private string zip = string.Empty;
private Int64 phoneNumber;
private string billingMethod = string.Empty;
private string ccType = string.Empty;
private Int64 ccNumber;


private void ReadXml(){

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(payload)) {
                xd = XDocument.Load(sr);
            }
            var node = xd.Root;
            //lets just make sure all the nodes we need are present, then continue
            //this is where billingMethod is assigned; after validating the Billing
            //node is present, it will check if I am getting credit card info or check                                                             
            //info, then assign "credit" or "check" to billingMethod
            ValidateNeededNodesPresent(node);
            if (errors.Count > 0) {
                Response();
                return;
            }
            //verify the nodes are not null, and assign them
            firstName= VerifyString(node.Element(XmlKey.FirstName).Value, XmlKey.FirstName);
            lastName= VerifyString(node.Element(XmlKey.LastName).Value, XmlKey.LastName);
            zip = ValidateStringMax(node.Element(XmlKey.Zip).Value, XmlKey.Zip, 5);
            email = VerifyString(node.Element(XmlKey.Email).Value, XmlKey.Email);
            address= VerifyString(node.Element(XmlKey.Address).Value, XmlKey.Address);
            city= ValidateData(node.Element(XmlKey.City).Value, XmlKey.City);
            phoneNumber = VerifyInt64(node.Element(XmlKey.PhoneNumber).Value, XmlKey.PhoneNumber);

            if(billingMethod == "credit")
            {
                ccNumber = VerifyInt64(node.Element(XmlKey.Billing).Element(XmlKey.CCNumber).Value,                                      XmlKey.CCdNumber);
                ccType = VerifyString(
                    node.Element(XmlKey.Billing).Element(XmlKey.CCType).Value, XmlKey.CCType);

            }

}
```

Now, here is my list of verify classes that check to make sure the data is not null and in the correct format (`int`, `int64`, `DateTime`, etc.). If it is not in the correct format, it will add an error to errors. The way is grabs errors is by getting the error string from a dictionary, where the key is the XML node name, and the value is the error message:

```cs
public Int64 VerifyInt64(string data, string element)
        {
            Int64 number = 0L;
            if (!Int64.TryParse(data, out number) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                errors.Add(ErrorDictionary.Errors[element]);

            }
            return number;

        }

public string VerifyString(string data, string element)
        {
             if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            errorMessages.Add(ErrorDictionary.Errors[element]);
        }
        return data;
        }

public string VerifyStringMax(string data, string element, int lengthMax)
        {
            if (data.Length > lengthMax || String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                errors.Add(ErrorDictionary.Errors[element]);

            }
            return data;
        }
```

The code works fine, but I cant help but think that I did more than I needed to. I'm strictly speaking about how I'm reading the XML, validating data, and assigning values in this case.

Is this code efficient? Is there a better way I can go about reading XML data and assigning values while validating the data?

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to verify the document structure, you may try using an XSD.  Once you have a schema doc defined, [you can use some LINQ to XML extensions to perform the validation and get the error messages (if any) that result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx).  Additionally, you can [use XSD to define default values for missing elements/attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp).

Once you do that, the code can be simplified:

```
        firstName= (string) node.Element(XmlKey.FirstName);
        lastName= (string) node.Element(XmlKey.LastName);
        zip = (string) node.Element(XmlKey.Zip);
        email = (string) node.Element(XmlKey.Email);
        address= (string) node.Element(XmlKey.Address);
        city= (string) node.Element(XmlKey.City);
        phoneNumber = (long) node.Element(XmlKey.PhoneNumber);

        if(billingMethod == "credit")
        {
            var  billingElement = node.Element(XmlKey.Billing);
            ccNumber = (long) billingElement.Element(XmlKey.CCNumber);
            ccType = (string) billingElement.Element(XmlKey.CCType);
        }
```

Though, to be honest, this feels like you would save a lot of work having a data object for a user that can be serialized/deserialized via a [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) rather than hand-building and parsing.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the XML from a 3rd party, so having any XML with XSD is out of the question.

Comment: @Chris Why? You don't need to store the XSD definition in the XML file. See this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048764/validate-xml-schema-using-msxml-parser).

Comment: You may note that the example provided within the first link does not put any XSD reference in the XML that is validated.  While it is nice to have a reference to the XSD within the XML (when using the document in XML editors), it is not required for the LINQ to XML validation to work.